# Creating a stop in a While loop - Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I am working on a code that is supposed to use a while loop to determine if the number inputted by the user is the same as the variable secret_number = 777.
the following criteria are:

will ask the user to enter an integer number;

will use a while loop;

will check whether the number entered by the user is the same as the number picked by the magician. If the number chosen by the user is different than the magician's secret number, the user should see the message "Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!" and be prompted to enter a number again.

If the number entered by the user matches the number picked by the magician, the number should be printed to the screen, and the magician should say the following words: "Well done, muggle! You are free now."

if you also have any tips how to use the while loop that would be really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Best if you can put the condition in the `while` statement itself, but if you need to exit the loop elsewhere, you can use `break`, possibly accompanied by `while True:` for an otherwise infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it's done:

```
secret_number = 777

n = int(input("Enter an integer number: "))

if n != secret_num: # If statement to chack if the numbers match
    print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")
    while True:
        input("Enter an integer number: ") # Loop never ends...

print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.") # If the program made it here, that means the user's number matched
```

Output:

```
Enter an integer number: 7
Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!
Enter an integer number: 2
Enter an integer number: 2
Enter an integer number: 3
Enter an integer number: 4
Enter an integer number: 56
Enter an integer number: 789
Enter an integer number:
Enter an integer number: 8765
Enter an integer number:
...
```

Round 2:

```
Enter an integer number: 777
Well done, muggle! You are free now.
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can escape from the loop using `break`.

For example:

```
secret_number = 777

while True:
    number = int(input("Enter an integer: "))    
    if number == secret_number:
        break
    print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")

print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
```

It is often better for sake of more comprehensible code to put the condition in the `while` statement itself if possible, rather than break from the loop elsewhere.  However, for this problem, the code needed to achieve that might require something like this, where the necessary restructuring of the code is probably not worthwhile compared to accepting the need to use `break`:

```
def get_number():
    return int(input("Enter an integer: "))

secret_number = 777

number = get_number()
while number != secret_number:
    print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")
    number = get_number()      

print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
```

However, in python 3.8, the "walrus operator" (`:=`) -- which allows a value to be simultaneously assigned to a variable and also used in an expression -- can be used to good effect to simplify the structure while avoiding the need for `break`:

```
secret_number = 777

while (number := int(input("Enter an integer: "))) != secret_number:
    print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")

print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
```

Of course, if you are not interested in storing the value, then you can just omit the use of the variable `number`, and then a similar structure becomes possible without the need for `:=`.

```
secret_number = 777

while int(input("Enter an integer: ")) != secret_number:
    print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")

print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use while(true) to create a while loop.
Inside, set a if/else to compare the value input and secret_number. If it's true, print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.") and *break*. Unless, print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop") and *continue*

Comment: There is no need for `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my examples:

Example 1:

```
secret_number = 777
guess_number = int(input("Enter a number: "))

while guess_number != secret_number:
    print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")
    guess_number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        
print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
```

Example 2:

```
secret_number = 777
guess_number = int(input("Enter a number: "))

while True:
    if guess_number == secret_number:
        print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
        break
    else:
        print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")
        guess_number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve this using this code:

```html
secret_number = 777

print(
"""
+================================+
| Welcome to my game, muggle!    |
| Enter an integer number        |
| and guess what number I've     |
| picked for you.                |
| So, what is the secret number? |
+================================+
""")
inp_number = int(input("Pick a number or Type 0 to stop "))
while inp_number != 0:
    if inp_number != secret_number:
        print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")
        inp_number = input("Pick a number or Type 0 to stop ")
    else:
        print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
secret_number = 777
print(
"""
+================================+
| Welcome to my game, muggle!    |
| Enter an integer number        |
| and guess what number I've     |
| picked for you.                |
| So, what is the secret number? |
+================================+
""")
a = int(input("Enter here: "))

while a!= secret_number:
        print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")
        a = int(input("Try again: "))

print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

````py
secret_number = 777

print(
"""
+================================+
| Welcome to my game, muggle!    |
| I've picked a number for you.  |
| So, what is the secret number? |
+================================+
""")

number = int(input("enter an integer..."))
# there's no need of if statement

while number != secret_number:
        print("Ha ha! You're stuck in my loop!")
        # ask again
        number = int(input("enter an integer..."))
        
print("Well done, muggle! You are free now.")```
````

Answer (score -1):

We can do it using while true and if as follows:

```
secret_number= 777
number=int(input("enter an integer..."))

while True:
    if number!= secret_number:
        print(number, "Ha ha! You’re stuck in my loop")
        #ask again
        number=int(input("enter an integer..."))
    else:
        print("Well done muggle! You are free now.")
# here we need to break it as user has entered the secret_number
        break
```